# Loader is required to be configured to import images using Vite?

Tags: vue.js, build, vite

I have a vue project which uses Vite in place of Webpack, and when I try to use `import x from './src/assets/my/path/to/image.png'` to resolve an image to compile-time URL, I am greeted by the following error message:

> ✘ [ERROR] No loader is configured for ".png" files: src/assets/my/path/to/image.png

The entire project is pretty close to the scaffold project given by `npm init vue@latest` (using vue3) so my `vite.config.js` is pretty basic:

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue(), VitePWA({})],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": fileURLToPath(new URL("./src", import.meta.url)),
    },
  },
  build: {
    manifest: true,
    polyfillModulePreload: true,
  }
});
```

What am I missing? How can I configure this? I can't find anything in Vite documentation about loaders.

Answer (score 0):

I had a quite similar issue with my project that I couldn't really solve. The issue seemed that only initially loaded png files were added. Because I am new to Vite, my efforts with the `vite.config.js` were fruitless.

Instead, I found a different solution to import the assets (`import img from '/path/to/img.png'` ) in respective js files directly instead of `vite.config.js`. Since I used these assets for replacement images for toggling buttons, it was a quick fix. Maybe it helps you, too.